# how do i can generate dynamic anchor tag with dynamic click event in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, anchor

When I'm clicking on anchor tag, page gets postback and does nothing

Code is as shown below,

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor anchor1 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor();                    
anchor1.InnerText = "Edit";
anchor1.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");                    
anchor1.Attributes.Add("onServerClick", "anchor1_Click");                 
anchor1.Style.Add("color", "blue");
anchor1.Style.Add("float", "right");

protected void anchor1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "msg", "alert('Enter Value For Drop Down Name');", true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Try this please

```
anchor1.ServerClick += new EventHandler(anchor1_Click);
```

Answer (score 0):

Give an attempt like this,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor anchor1 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor();
  anchor1.InnerText = "Edit";
  anchor1.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");                
  anchor1.Style.Add("color", "blue");
  anchor1.Style.Add("float", "right");
  anchor1.ServerClick += new EventHandler(anchor1_Click);
}

protected void anchor1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "msg", "alert('Enter Value For Drop Down Name');", true);

}
```